# How to obtain the parameters of unknown frequency hopping signal?

Tags: matlab

Has any body done the parameter estimation of unknown frequency hopping signals using matlab?

Comment: Please describe what you have tried so far. That includes which references you have looked at and such. Also if you are facing a specific issue while attempting to solve this problem. Your question is too general.

Comment: FH is a technique,in which the signal is transmitted with certain carrier frequency(f1) for a fixed duration(let 0msec to 4msec),then another carrier frequency(f2) for next fixed duration (4msec to 8msec) and so on. I am using 10 frequencies to transmit a signal of duration 100msec and repeating the same frequencies after 40msec duration time.So it contains 10 frequencies each for a duration 4msec in 40msec duration signal and then same 10 frequencies for the next 40msec duration signal and so on till signal completes.we need the estimate the pattern of frequencies used for sending the signal.